# How to get Security Filtering property of a certain GPO on client?

Tags: active-directory, operating-system, gpo

Nowadays I am building active directory in our company and I am facing some problems.

I just want to get the delegation property of a certain GPO(Group Policy Object).
I know that `Get-GPPermissions` in powershell is for getting delegation properties of a GPO, but I have to setup RSAT on the client to do that.

Is there any solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need RSAT to be installed on your computer.

Just use:

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName myremotecomputer
```

to connect to a computer which has the PowerShell modules installed you want to use.